# java regex match a list only from 0-9, sequence matters

Tags: java, regex, list

I would like to develop a regex in java that only matches 0-9(sequence matters)

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  --> match
[7, 8]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] --> match
[1]
```

Comment: Why do you want a regexp for this? Just use plain text comparison, there is no complexity here that would require regular expressions.

Comment: I need to use regexp for matching [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and inverse matching the rest of lists.

Comment: Have you tried this regex `0123456789` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird you want to use a regex to do this, so I can come up with this idea:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
String regex = "0123456789";

String listStr = numbers.stream()
                        .map(number -> String.valueOf(number))
                        .collect(toStringJoiner(""));

if (listStr.matches(regex))
    System.out.println("match");
else
    System.out.println("not match");
```

The idea is to flatten your number list to a single string and then compare it to the `0123456789` string... so you can use:

```
if (listStr.matches(regex))    // regex approach
if (listStr.equals(regex))     // or equals approach
                               (not sure why you want a regex)
```

Comment: If the list is `(0,123,4567,89)`, this solution will fail. And I don't understand why string conversion is necessary. Seems like a hell lot of works just for a simple task.

Comment: Another thing: `toStringJoiner` seems to be present in the preview (Java 8 b00), but it has been changed to `Collectors.joining()` in official release.